# Azure Data Factory cache sink contains only a subset of data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In data flow that includes cache sink only a subset of data seems to be available as an output for the next activity, although it seems that sink activity itself reads all the records
[Sink contains all the records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHgjq.png)

Somehow when run as dataflow activity the number of rows in sink output is 145 not 1120. What can be a reason?

I have tried to use a single partition but it did not affect the result. Also, it is the same number of records for the bigger data set. Is there some kind of limit?

Definition of dataflow activity:

```
{
"name": "Data flow1",
"type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
"dependsOn": [],
"policy": {
    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
    "retry": 0,
    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
    "secureOutput": false,
    "secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
    "dataflow": {
        "referenceName": "create_batch_dataflow",
        "type": "DataFlowReference"
    },
    "compute": {
        "coreCount": 8,
        "computeType": "General"
    },
    "traceLevel": "None",
    "cacheSinks": {
        "firstRowOnly": false
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide your dataflow sink confugurations or dataflow JSON?

Comment: If we are talking about the the rows you want to put into another activity after your dataflow, but not inside the dataflow itself, The output from the data flow that is injected directly into your pipeline is limited to 2MB.

Comment: @pzien, Also can you rename your cache sink to a custom name and try and see if it comes up as 'Cached Lookup' under expression elements in a dynamic expression creator window?

Comment: Supporting @ZiyaMertKarakas answer. 2MB limitation is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-data-flow-activity#first-row-only

Answer (score 0):

I guess the output dataset is exceeding payload limitations of the next activity input and then it gets truncated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its about the 2mb size limitation of cache.